# Jenkins upload artifact to nexus plugin

Tags: maven, jenkins

Could you please help me in providing any alternate solution or plugin which will help me to upload my artifacts to Nexus 3.x.

My ground work says that Development is in progress for Nexus Artifact Plugin. I am lost here so need anyone guidance on the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now the Nexus Artifact Uploader plugin supports uploading artifacts to Nexus-3.x.
Support for Nexus-3.x from the version Nexus-Artifact-Uploader 2.6